# Is there a way to make both faces from upper and below mesh the same so I can Bridge Edge Loop these two without distortion?

Tags: mesh, vertices

[image][image][image: after joining both mesh it's breaking a little bit the smoothness on the sides]I was trying to edge loop the two surfaces but the upper mesh it's straight, I tried setting 64 vertices in both but because the shapes are different edge loops creates distortion, is there a way to make them the same? Or there's another way for joining smoothly these two shapes?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][[image: basically I want to smooth it as the reference imageSides are going out a bit]

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have an image of your reference object?

Comment: yes, just learned how to add it, sorry, first time in forum

Comment: no I mean what object are your trying to model?

Comment: First of all, in the file you uploaded those are two separate objects. To bridge the edge loops you need to join the objects with Ctrl+J. Then you have duplicate vertices on the bottom face of the upper object. It looks like 4 but there are 12. So select all with A, then M > Merge > By Distance. But even then I don't see where you have set 64 vertices...? The upper object has 70 overall before merging and 62 after merging. But even with 2 more, for bridging them the connecting edge needs 64 vertices, not the object as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better work a low-poly version rather than trying to fix a high-poly, but if we start from your version, first thing join the 2 objects (<kbd>J</kbd>), select all in *Edit* mode and merge the overlapping vertices (<kbd>M</kbd>), remove the bottom face of the top part, subdivide the bottom of the top part in order to get 64 vertices (first select 2 sides, subdivide 26, select the perpendicular sides and subdivide 4):

[image]

[image]

Then bridge the two parts with the *LoopTools* (you first need to activate the *LoopTools* addon):

[image]

Once bridged, you can tweak some parameters in the *Operator Box* if necessary (like *Segments* and *Twist*):

[image]

If it needs to be curvy, select the middle edge, scale it down and bevel:

[image]

Comment: If you don't merge the duplicate vertices before subdividing the edges your solution can get messy very quickly ;)

Comment: Oh ok I'm going to edit

Comment: I hate to be nitpicky, but much too often it is not easy for newbies to make the obvious things for cleaning up the mesh, and afterwards they wonder why the proposed solutions don't work.

Comment: Yes it's just that I forgot I did it  ;)

Comment: Remember to delete the bottom face of the top object so you don't end up with an internal face. Also consider CTRL+E - bridge edge loops, where you can set "blend surface" interpolation, together with increased number of cuts giving a smooth transition: https://i.imgur.com/gGscgKI.gif

Comment: Oh yes you're right I thought the bottom face would be automatically removed

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The internal faces get removed automatically, at least if you don't change the default setting having _Remove faces_ enabled, as it is shown in the screenshot.

Comment: thank you so much everyone! I was using bridge edge loop instead of loop tool, loop tool worked way better, and you're right gordon, I was having just the same problem of messy mesh without cleaning lol. Now I was wondering how I can clean up or make smooth the transition between the two meshes, smooth vertices it's distorting the shape, before was asked what I was trying to model, I will add new pictures

Comment: You need to shade smooth and in the Object Data panel > Normal, enable Auto Smooth and tweak the value.If it's still not good please share your file